# Why are the form inputs in my html table unclickable?

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-template, ng-container

I am trying to render a table in html that is the representation of a reactive form array.

I loop over the complex object (FormGroup > FormArray > FormGroup > FormArray) With the final array being the data that we want to represent to the UI in its transformed format. (Happens in the function groupFormGroup())

Everything works fine, the data is correctly transformed and displayed.

However, now I am trying to add inputs (NOT formControlName inputs) to the table and when they load, they load without me being able to click into, or change their value. They are not disabled, just unclickable. No errors come up in the console.

What I have tried:

1. Modifying the class names so it is no longer class='form-control'
2. Increasing the z-index of inputs to be on the forefront
3. Making the inputs position relative

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="address">
            <div class="col-12">
              <table class="w-100">
                <thead>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Order ID</th>
                  <th>GP Code</th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Preset Suite Number</th>
                  <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <ng-template formArrayName="addressOrders" ngFor let-addressOrder [ngForOf]="address.get('addressOrders').controls" let-ao="index">
                    <ng-container [formGroup]="addressOrder">
                      <ng-template ngFor let-fulfillment [ngForOf]="groupFormGroup(addressOrder.get('fulfillments').getRawValue(),'orderDetailId')" let-f="index">
                        <tr>
                          <td class='table-input'>
                            <input type="checkbox" 
                            (change)="updateFulfillmentFormControl(fulfillment,addressOrder,'selected',$event)"/>
                          </td>
                          <td>{{addressOrder.get('orderId').value}}</td>
                          <td>{{fulfillment['gpItemNumber']}}</td>
                          <td>{{fulfillment['name']}}</td>
                          <td>{{fulfillment['quantity']}}</td>
                          <td>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="fulfillment['isSuite']">
                              <!-- <input class="form-control" (keydown)="updateFulfillmentFormControl(fulfillment,addressOrder,'suiteNumber',$event)" /> -->
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                            </ng-container>
                          </td>
                          <td>Edit Detail</td>
                        </tr>
                      </ng-template>
                    </ng-container>
                  </ng-template>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And the code generating the Form Group:

```
draw() {
    this.formGroup = this.initFormGroup(this.ordersToDisplay)
}

initFormGroup(ordersToDisplay: Array<BulkFulfillCustomer>):FormGroup {
    var queueList = this.queues.map(q => q['queue_id']);
    return this.fb.group({
      customers: this.fb.array(
        ordersToDisplay.map(otd => {
          return this.fb.group({
            gpCustomerNumber:[otd.gpCustomerNumber],
            customerName:[otd.customerName],
            customerAddresses: this.initAddressForm(otd.addressOrders, queueList)
          })
        })
      ) 
    })
  }

  initAddressForm(addressOrders: Array<BulkFulfillAddress>, queues:Array<string>):FormArray {
    return this.fb.array(
      addressOrders.map(ao => {
        return this.fb.group({
          addressLine:[ao.addressLine],
          bundleShipment:[true],
          addressOrders: this.initAddressOrdersForm(ao.orders,queues)
        })
      })
    )
  }

  initAddressOrdersForm(orders: Array<BulkFulfillOrder>, queues:Array<string>):FormArray {
    return this.fb.array(
      orders.map(o => {
        return this.fb.group({
          orderId: [o.order.id],
          fulfillments: this.initFulfillmentsForm(o.orderDetailFulfillments,queues)
        })
      })
    )
  }
  
  initFulfillmentsForm(fulfillments: Array<FulfillmentLine>, queues:Array<string>) {
    return this.fb.array(
      fulfillments.map(f => {
        return this.fb.group({
          selected:[true],
          expandDetail:[false],
          isSuite:[f.inventory.isSuite],
          suitePrefix:[f.inventory.suitePrefix],
          gpItemNumber:[f.inventory.gpItemNumber],
          name:[f.inventory.name],
          queueId:[{value:f.inventory.pulseQueueId,disabled:(!this.isPulseFulfill && f.inventory.fulfillmentMethod != INVENTORY_FULFILLMENT_PULSE)}, Validators.compose([Validators.required, ContainsListValidator(queues,'Queue ID')])],
          orderDetailId:[f.orderDetailFulfillment.orderDetailId],
          pulseOrderId:[f.orderDetailFulfillment.pulseOrderId],
          suiteNumber:[{value:f.orderDetailFulfillment.suiteNumber,disabled:!this.isPulseFulfill || !f.inventory.isSuite}, Validators.required],
          quantity:[{value:f.orderDetailFulfillment.quantity,disabled:f.orderDetailFulfillment.fulfillmentMethod != 1},Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(1),Validators.max(f.orderDetailFulfillment.quantity)])]
        })
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: can you possibly share a stackblitz? it may be a lot easier with the code in your ts file so we can see the actual form element

Comment: Hi, I can't share a stackblitz, but I will update the code to show the structure of the form group

Comment: Thank you, Ill try and take a look.... Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Nope, no errors